# Clarification on finance math

Tags: finance

Given the problem:

A bank account pays interest with continuous compounding at the rate
of 6% per annum. What is the value of an initial deposit of $700 after
3 months? after 1.7 years?

From what I understand, the formula is $$A=Pe^{rt}$$

My question is about the 1.7 years. Can I just use 1.7 as my $t$? Is it as simple as that?

Comment: Yes it is as simple as that. For three months remember to use $t=0.25$, not $t=0.3$.